# OpenStreetMapProvider license

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, gmap.net

I am writing Windows Forms commercial application. I have functionality that get data from gps, latitude and longitude and show the actual position on the OpenStreetMap. I use GMap .NET and OpenStreetMapProvider. I searched over internet and there is a information that is free to use if you write information about authors and link information about license. But also i found this [a link](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/36745/openstreetmap-in-non-web-application)! and I am not sure if its free in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really tell in detail how you will use OSM. If you just want to show OSM tiles then adding an attribution (copyright and link to licence) is enough.

See [OSM Licence and Legal FAQ](https://wiki.osmfoundation.org/wiki/Licence/Licence_and_Legal_FAQ) for details. If in doubt, contact a lawyer.